# Swift 5 Where are NSUserDefault.standard value stored on macOS

Tags: swift

I have a macOS project Swift 5. I need to store userDefault values. Based on the values users will be granted access to premium features of my app. I like to know if a user is able to view files on their macOS operating system to retrieve the userDefault.standard  values.

Basically trying to prevent users from hacking the app. Will users have access and able to change the userDefault values from there file system on there macOS

Example

```
UserDefaults.standard(true, forKey: "premium")
```

can a user edit a file on system to change this value.
`"where/the/path/to/user/defaults"`

Comment: Yes by using the command `defaults write` from the command line. So you should research this to evaluate it to see if UserDefailts is usable for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user will be able to view them with appropriate tools and alter them. For sensitive information, Id recommends using Keychain.
Even better have this logic implemented on the server side to give you full control over this feature.